# Passing of 2D array into function- why do I need to include column number instead of row number?

Tags: arrays

In the passing of a 2D array into a function, why do I have to specify the column size (i.e. how many columns does my array have)?

Can it work the other way round- instead of specifying the column size I specify the number of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a table into which you haven't entered any data.

If you do not specify the number of columns, every time you enter new data, it goes into the next column in the first row, and this goes on until all the data is entered. But then all the data is entered in the first row itself, making your table a single row, that's a 1-D array, not a 2-D array.

But if you specify the number of columns, when you hit the limit when entering data, the next piece of data goes to the next set of columns (i.e. the 2nd row) automatically, thus a table is formed.

No, you cannot specify only the number of rows.

Hope I helped!

Comment: I get it now. Thank you! :)